# Unable to access puppet enterprise web console

Tags: virtualbox, puppet

Hi I am beginner to puppet. I have setup **learning puppet VM with virtual box 4.3.7** on win 7. Other puppet commands are running properly, but I am unable to access Puppet enterprise web console.

I have tried it using "`https://ip_address_of_vm`" on a web browser on win 7. I have tried to ping that ip address on command prompt, still its not connecting to it.

What should I do? Any kind of help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the NIC is set to 'bridged' mode in VMWare/Virtualbox.

Also, can you ping the ipaddress?

Comment: after setting the NIC in virtual box to bridged adapter mode,
the "facter ipaddress" command is also not displaying the IPaddress.
Its output is "Timed out seeking value of IPaddress"

Answer (score 1):

To get mine to work, I changed my VirtualBox VM network settings to 'Host-only Adapter'.

`facter ipaddress` then returned a working IP.

I am running OSX 10.8.5 and VirtualBox 4.3.8